# Link to change language of site

Tags: dynamic

Does anyone know or recommend a method for a simple way to convert a site into a different language. I just need the site to change from spanish to english and vice versa, but the site will load in spanish first. Perhaps a plugin is available? Most of the content is dynamic and the site is being developed with Concrete5 CMS. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to install an add-on for this. Check out Internationalization, it's free: http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/internationalization/

Here is a YouTube video showing it in action, so you can quickly see if it's what you had in mind: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hd936iaDLqw&feature=player_embedded

Answer (score 0):

You need some **automatic translation** tool (since you said your content is dynamic).
There are many in internet, you just have to search for *"Automatic translation API"*.
I recommend you using the [Google Translate one](http://googleblog.blogspot.com.es/2009/09/translate-your-website-with-google.html).